# Block Chance VS Mitigation

Tags: everquest-2

Everquest 2 level 95 Berserker here and I dont know what to use! Do I opt for Block Chance gear, Mitigation gear, or a mix of both? (if both: what is ideal?)

I am attempting to create a build that will benefit my team in high-end heroic and raid level dungeons, but I am not certain which of these stats will contribute more to my longevity, making the healers' job easier. If anyone could enlighten me on what is best, or perhaps the mathematical formula used to determine the outcome of these stats in damage calculation, I would very much appreciate it!